# equivalent python and pandas operation for group_by + mutate + indexing column vectors within mutate in R

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

Sample data frame in Python:

```
d = {'col1': ["a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "b", "c", "c", "c"], 
     'col2': [3, 4, 5, 1, 3, 9, 5, 7, 23]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

Now I want to get the same output in Python with pandas as I get in R with the code below. So I want to get the change in percentage in col1 by group in col2.

```
data.frame(col1 = c("a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "b", "c", "c", "c"),
           col2 = c(3, 4, 5, 1, 3, 9, 16, 18, 23)) -> df

df %>%
  dplyr::group_by(col1) %>%
  dplyr::mutate(perc = (dplyr::last(col2) - col2[1]) / col2[1])
```

In python, I tried:

```
def perc_change(column):
    index_1 = tu_in[column].iloc[0]
    index_2 = tu_in[column].iloc[-1]
    perc_change = (index_2 - index_1) / index_1  
    return(perc_change)    

d = {'col1': ["a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "b", "c", "c", "c"], 
     'col2': [3, 4, 5, 1, 3, 9, 5, 7, 23]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df.assign(perc_change = lambda x: x.groupby["col1"]["col2"].transform(perc_change))
```

But it gives me an error saying: 'method' object is not subscriptable.

I am new to python and trying to convert some R code into python. How can I solve this in an elegant way? Thank you!

Comment: Oops sorry. I didn't notice that you defined your own user function. Can you provide the expected output, because I no longer think mine is correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't want `transform` here. `transform` is typically used when your aggregation returns a scalar value per group and you want to broadcast that result to all rows that belong to that group in the original DataFrame. Because `GroupBy.pct_change` already returns a result indexed like the original, you aggregate and assign back.

```
df['perc_change'] = df.groupby('col1')['col2'].pct_change()

#  col1  col2  perc_change
#0    a     3          NaN
#1    a     4     0.333333
#2    a     5     0.250000
#3    b     1          NaN
#4    b     3     2.000000
#5    b     9     2.000000
#6    c     5          NaN
#7    c     7     0.400000
#8    c    23     2.285714
```

But if instead what you need is the overall percentage change within a group, so it's the difference in the first and last value divided by the first value, you would then want transform.

```
df.groupby('col1')['col2'].transform(lambda x: (x.iloc[-1] - x.iloc[0])/x.iloc[0])

0    0.666667
1    0.666667
2    0.666667
3    8.000000
4    8.000000
5    8.000000
6    3.600000
7    3.600000
8    3.600000
Name: col2, dtype: float64
```